# Validating JSON/Javascript objects using express-validate

Tags: node.js, json, express, react-hook-form, express-validator

I have a web app with a form that sends `multipart/form-data` to my Express server. The form contains various types of data; strings, numbers, objects/arrays and a file. Everything gets sent as a string due to the web app using `formData` and `JSON.stringify`.

I'm trying to set up validation using express-validator, and the issue I'm having is that the objects/arrays submitted via the form are JSON strings. Normally I would just use `JSON.parse` to convert them back into objects, but as express-validator is middleware, I don't think I can do that without mutating `req.body` in an earlier middleware function, which I don't think is a good idea, if it would even work.

In case it's relevant, I've provided some code that roughly demonstrates how I'm doing things below. If I'm doing something wrong there, please feel free to point it out.

posting from web app:

```js
const onSubmit = async data => {
    const formData = new FormData()

    try {
        Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            // if it's a string, send it as is
            // if it's not, stringify it
            // this avoids both a string being double-wrapped in quotation marks
            // and an object being sent as [Object object]
            formData.set(key, typeof value === 'string' ? value : JSON.stringify(value))
        })
        await api({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/myRoute/postForm',
            data: formData
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
}
```

`data` comes from react-hook-form and basically resembles:

```js
data = {
    someNumber: 100,
    someString: 'someValue',
    someObject: {
        name: 'an object',
        value: 1234
    },
    someArray: [{
        id: '1',
        name: 'ABC'
    },{
        id: '2',
        name: 'DEF'
    }]
}
```

express:

```js
const app = express()
app.disable('x-powered-by')
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback')
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true
}))
app.use(helmet())
app.use('/myRoute', myRoute)
myRoute.post(
    '/postform',

    upload.single('image'), // multer for handling the file upload

    body('someNumber').isInt({max: 10}), // should fail
    body('someObject').isObject(), // should pass but fails, due to req.body.someObject being a JSON string
    body('someObject.name').notEmpty(), // ^^
    body('someObject.value').isInt({min: 1000}) // ^^
    // more validation, etc

    (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req)
        console.log(errors)
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                errors: errors.array()
            })
        }
        res.sendStatus(200)
    }
)
```

I've Google'd a lot to try and figure this out, and I've noticed that for a lot of other people, their `req.body.someObject` would simply be a JavaScript object, rather than a JSON string, seemingly without anything special taking place.

Am I doing something wrong?
What can be done to have my `req.body.someObject` and similar fields as JavaScript objects for express-validator rather than JSON?

Comment: I don't see any harm in parsing it via a prior middleware. Surely nothing is going to consume it as a string.